# SharePoint 2013 workflow history page issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

When trying to open Workflow page, `An unexpected error has occured` exception throws.

And in the log `Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may occur because of

1. You didn't have sufficient permission on the history list.
2. Workflow Manager Backend Service is not running.
3. Workflow manager proxy is not connected.

**Regarding (1)**

Make sure at the Root SharePoint Site to that the users that use this workflow have

- `Limited Access` to Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or documents when given permissions.
- And as `contribute` to the SharePoint list that has the workflow with its related `Task List` and `History list`.

You may also need to check how to elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013 by doing the following :

- Allow workflow to use app permissions.
- Grant full control permission to a workflow.
- Develop the workflow to wrap actions inside an App Step using SharePoint Designer.

For more details about How to apply the above steps check [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

**Regarding (2)**

Make sure that Workflow Manager Backend Service is started

[image]

**Regarding (3)**

Make sure that Workflow manager proxy is connected

> Application Management > Application Services > Click on Workflow Service Application Proxy.

[image]

- Last option is to check the latest CU that has been installed , it's preferred to apply Service Pack 1 if it's not applied where maybe this issue solved at it.
  hope it helped you.

See also

- [How to install and configure Workflow Manager](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/).
- [How to register workflow manager](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/12/register-spworkflowservice-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-service/)

Comment: Dear @samdaniel ,take your time to test this solution that I hope it helps you, and If this answer is useful. please  upvote it and if it considered an answer to your question you should also set it as Answer, I am also here if you need any clarification.